# Kong path parameter always null

Tags: kong

Lately I've been working on Kong (free version), I tried to create a service with the Admin API as follow:

`http POST :8081/services name=some_api path='/some_path' host=$host url=$url`

The service is created but the path parameter seems to always end up null in the created object.

Did I miss something while creating the service or did the synthax changed ?

If anyone has an idea, It would be lovely !

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `url` parameter:

> Shorthand attribute to set `protocol`, `host`, `port` and `path` at once. This attribute is write-only (the Admin API never returns the URL).

You are overwriting your `path` parameter with this one.

You should use `protocol`, `host`, `port`, `path` or just `url`

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback ! It fixed everything thank you !

Comment: Can you mark as correct answer if it is all good?